# Optimizing SQL query being slowed by bookmark lookup

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I've hit a bit of a road block with this query I've written due to a bookmark lookup which it is performing at the end of its execution. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions to work around this problem. Query below:

```
select 
isNull(a.groupname, b.groupname) groupname,  
isNull(a.gName, b.gName) gName,  
isNull(a.sab_count, 0) as sab_count,  
isNull(b.prdb_count, 0) as prdb_count 
from 
( select g.gid, groupname, gName, count(p.pid) as sab_count 
from 
( select  gid, 'g00' + convert(varchar(1), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where    gid < 10 
union 
select  gid, 'g0' + convert(varchar(2), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid   > 10 and gid < 100 
union 
select  gid, 'g' + convert(varchar(3), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid > 100 ) g, panelists p 
where p.groups like '%' + groupname + '%' and p.validated in (1,2,3,4) 
group by g.gid, groupname, gName ) a 
FULL OUTER JOIN  
( select g.gid, groupname, gName, count(p.prid) as prdb_count 
from 
( select  gid, 'g00' + convert(varchar(1), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where  gid < 10 
union 
select  gid, 'g0' + convert(varchar(2), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid > 10 and gid < 100 
union 
select  gid, 'g' + convert(varchar(3), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid > 100 ) g, prdb p 
where p.groups like '%' + groupname + '%' 
and p.valid in (0,1)
group by g.gid, groupname, gName ) b on a.gid = b.gid 
order by isNull(a.gName, b.gName)
```

"and p.valid in (0,1)" is where the bookmark is being used. I've been trying a few different things based on other posts I've read but was wondering if anyone had a fresh idea.

Comment: How about posting the exact schema definition? Tables, indexes.

Comment: This immediately stands out: `where p.groups like '%' + groupname + '%'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as a case statement

```
select  gid, 'g00' + convert(varchar(1), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where    gid < 10  
union  
select  gid, 'g0' + convert(varchar(2), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid   > 10 and gid < 100  
union  
select  gid, 'g' + convert(varchar(3), gid) as groupname, gName from groups g where gid > 100 
) -- u r selecting whole table ? u will throw off optimizer 

select gid, case
            when gid < 10 then 'g00'
            when gid < 100 then 'g0'
            when gid > 100 then 'g' 
            end  + .. same follows for convert
from groups g
```

Actually I think u do not even need a case....